# How do you view the structure of data stored in a Python variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

Im coming from an R background where it is trivial to do `str(X)` to get a text output of a data structure and its values. Is there a similar functionality in Python?

Note that in Python `type(X)` does not return the data structure- just the class of X which is not what I am looking for.

`print(X)` returns the values but not their type (num in the R code below)

Example using R of my goal:

```
> df<-data.frame(1,2,3)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X1: num 1
 $ X2: num 2
 $ X3: num 3
```

Comment: What do you mean by data structure?

Comment: If you're talking about pandas, there's `df.dtypes`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thats it, I was looking for a way to tell what tye the values returned by something like print() were. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There many variants to print smth in python ***represented as common data structures*** . I prefere *pprint* - https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html.

```
     import pprint

     pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
     pp.pprint(df) # df in your case
```

Another variant we can use json serializer:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(df, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

If you realy asked about ***Pandas Dataframe*** you can use any library for df pritty print:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable

Also pprint works with DF too.
Another way is to use nattive Pandas mathod: `df.shape` - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html

---

But if you come from R (and RStudio), maybe you will like ***Jupyter*** http://jupyter.org/ - it displays all you need in good, pritty and interactive way. Little turtorial: http://songhuiming.github.io/pages/2017/04/02/jupyter-and-pandas-display/

Comment: + I know one good tutorial (my favoutrite ), but on Russian,  - https://habrahabr.ru/company/ods/blog/322626/ . But you can only scrole it and look up pictures-screanshoots, they realy nice.